# Is this the expected behavior of Javascript Prototype property?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

```
function math() { return 'x' } 

math.prototype.sqrt = function(a){return Math.sqrt(a)} 

var x = new math(); 
x.sqrt(9); //gives 3

function math1() { return {} } 

math1.prototype.sqrt = function(a){return Math.sqrt(a)} 

var y = new math1(); 
y.sqrt(9); //throws javascript error "TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'sqrt'"
```

Comment: Nice question. I learned something today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally there is nothing to be achieved from returning a value from an constructor. It seems that if a JavaScript primitive such as a number or string are returned, the object instantiation process with `new` (`var y = new math1();`) works as you would expect, ignoring this value.

However it seems if you return a JavaScript object such as `{}` the instantiation process with `new` doesn't work in the same way. Instead your variable y is loaded with the object returned not with a new instance of math1.